# use rsa keys for ssh in setup.py install

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I'm developing a python package that upon installation needs to use SSH to interact with remote servers. I have RSA key verification for all the servers I would like to connect to for my user, but I need to run the setup.py install with root privilages. Unfortunately, root can't seem to use the RSA keys I have, so I tried to run commands from the setup.py with lowered permissions but it didn't work. example to check if RSA keys are working:
after running `sudo python` in the command line, in the python environment:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['ssh','-oBatchMode=yes',host])
```

gives `Permission denied (publickey,password).`

running just `python` in the command line and running the same script works

running `sudo python` in the command line and then:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['sudo','-u','pi','ssh','-oBatchMode=yes',host])
```

gives the same error

running `sudo python` then:

```
call(['sudo','-u','pi','whoami'])
```

returns `pi` as would be expected

Why can't I access my RSA keys this way? What can I do to make this work?

Comment: How do you feed script with RSA key ? From file, or by ssh agent ? If you are using ssh agent, sudo drops SSH_AUTH_SOCK env variable and disables ssh agent.

Comment: Yeah I was using ssh-agent. So should I just called ssh-agent again after running the script with sudo?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user